# display result divs based on web form radio button selections

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I would like to simply `.show()` a `div` based on a web forms radio button (user) selections.

For brevity lets take below *(but note I'm looking for somewhat scaleable advice as my web form will have 7 questions and 5 answers each. And I have 5 results `divs`)*

**Note://** So, basically there will be 7 questions and 5 answers each. so I will need an array with 5 possible answer combinations via user radio button selection, ideally using the input '`value`' field; so I can simply change the values of what value combos would equal what div results screen. *The div results screens will just be 5 unique sets of content inside the div, that's it.*

---

**Mark-Up:**

```
<div class="page1">
  <form class="sampler">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
  </form>
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="page2">
  <form class="sampler">
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="tacos" checked>Tacos
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="food" value="spicynuts">Rotten Spicy Peanuts
  </form>
</div>
```

---

```
<div id="resultsONE"><!-- one results div is display none by default sample but there would be much more content here  -->
  <p>Congratulations, you are NOT the father</p>
</div>
```

I know the below is terrible syntax; but this was the logic I was thinking about starting with on **JS** side. Note I will have 5 unique results `#divs`.

---

```
function resultsdivONE () { 
  if ($input value == "male" & "tacos") {
    $('#resultsONE').show();   
  } else if () {
    // do
  } else {
    // do
  }
}
```

---

As I mentioned above; I'm looking for a method where I can simply use the **SELECTED** input `value=""`; so they can be changed somewhat easily.

*Example.*

---

```
if ("male" & "tacos" & "nextanswer" & "nextanswerafter") { // etc up to 7
   $('#resultsONE').show(); 
 }  // first results div
```

---

*May be open to php options.*

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Where are the result divs? And based on your function, how are we supposed to know what combination of results should cause the div to be displayed?

Comment: Question has been updated.

Comment: Are you still looking for help on this?

Comment: Yeah, there's 6 days left on the bounty. I'll close it before then with what works.

Comment: Can you indicate what you find wrong about the current answers?  I've seen more than one that seems to answer the updated question.  It is really, really hard to give a better answer without finding out why the current answers aren't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## display result divs based on web form radio button selections

### What to achieve?

So basically, what is seeked is a simple form containing radio buttons and results which should match a combination of the radio-choices.According to the question, the questions should be easily maintainable and changable, without always touching a script or its initial logic.
*This votes for outsourcing the questions and the logic - seperate it from the DOM.*

### How to achieve that?

Shortly mentioned and furthermore visible in the question tags are php and ajax. Given that there might be the wish to outsource the questions completely and grab them from php by ajax. *Another vote for outsourcing.*

### What is needed to achieve that?

- Is there any framework and/or library required? Not necessarily, yet it could be usefull

  - To retrieve the JSON
  - To create DOM elements
- Do we need all the questions and answers in the DOM all time? Not really

> For brevity lets take below (but note I'm looking for somewhat scaleable advice as my web form will have 7 questions and 5 answers each. And I have 5 results divs)

1. I recommend to create the DOM on the fly, since - up until now- there is no reason to keep it all the time and it makes the HTML file itself look more slim and neat.
2. Additionally, it is possible to seperate the layout, structure, logic and the data, which in the end allows you to change the answers and questions by changing one file.
3. With a method like this, you could create more forms with different questions, yet the same code.
4. If you are not using any library/framework yet, do not add one just for this script.

### Conclusion

To make it easily maintainable, the questions and answers are going to be outsourced into a json file (here JSON.js). Given this, it is also possible to retrieve it by php or any webservice and/or store those in a database. Furthermore the possibility is provided to create multiple forms with yet different questions which all use the same code.

[There is a Fiddle available for it](https://jsfiddle.net/enomoh9c/)

### Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- optional styles -->
        <style>
            #Container{
                left: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            //This is out simple AJAX routine to not overload it by any framework.
            //If you are already using jQuery, just use $.get()
            ;var AJAX = {
                getXmlDoc: function(){return ((window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"))},

                //u:=url, f:=callback, c:=any param to pass to callback
                Get: function(u, f, c){
                    var tDoc = this.getXmlDoc();

                    tDoc.open('GET', u, true);
                    tDoc.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if (tDoc.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && tDoc.status === 200) f(tDoc, c);
                    };

                    tDoc.send();
                }
            };

            //This is going to be the namespace holding our functionality.
            //In the end one should outsource this to a script file, yet we leave it here in the example for a better overview.
            ;var Quiz = {
                mContainer: null, //In this container the quiz gets created in
                mCurrent: null, //Stores the current displayed question
                mJSON: null, //In here we are going to store the JSON result

                //Handling logical errors, like missing data or json
                _Error: function(m){
                    console.log(m)
                },

                //The event called on the radio change event
                //e:=element
                _onChange: function(e){
                    if (e && this.mJSON.questions[this.mCurrent]){
                        //We are going to those the result of this question in the JSON
                        this.mJSON.questions[this.mCurrent].value = e.value;

                        //If the question is not the last, we are going to display the next one
                        if (this.mCurrent < this.mJSON.questions.length - 1){
                            this.hideQuestions();
                            this.showQuestion(this.mCurrent + 1)
                        }
                        else{
                            //Else we are going to show the result
                            this.hideQuestions();
                            this.showResult()
                        }
                    }
                    else this._Error('_onChange(): Invalid parameters')
                },

                //The function to initialise our quiz.
                //We are going to grab the json data and analyse it.
                //c:=container element || document.body, l:=link || 'JSON.js'
                Init: function(c, l){
                    this.mContainer = (c || document.body);

                    var tL = (l || 'JSON.js');
                    AJAX.Get(tL, function(r, l){
                        Quiz.mJSON = JSON.parse(r.response);

                        if (Quiz.mJSON && Quiz.mJSON.questions)
                            Quiz.showQuestion(0)
                        else
                            Quiz._Error('Init(): No questions found with "' + l + '"')
                    }, tL)
                },

                //Hiding the previously asked questions (remove from dom)
                hideQuestions: function(){
                    while(this.mContainer.firstChild) this.mContainer.removeChild(this.mContainer.firstChild)
                },

                //Going to show the result according to the asked questions
                showResult: function(){
                    var tValues = []; //Storing our answers
                    for(var i=0, j=this.mJSON.questions.length; i<j; i++)
                        if (this.mJSON.questions[i].value) tValues.push(this.mJSON.questions[i].value)

                    //Going to store the result text
                    var tResult = 'No match for ' + tValues.join(',');

                    //Looping through all requirements to get a match
                    for(var i=0, j=this.mJSON.answers.length; i<j; i++){
                        //The requirements which need to match the values
                        var tR = this.mJSON.answers[i].requirement;

                        //For this we filter all the elements which do not match the requirements
                        var tF = tValues.filter(function(e){return tR.indexOf(e) === -1})

                        //If that list is empty, all elements matched and we can stop
                        if (!tF || tF.length === 0){
                            tResult = this.mJSON.answers[i].message;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //Now we are going to dislpay the result
                    var tH = document.createElement('h1');
                    tH.innerHTML = tResult;
                    this.mContainer.appendChild(tH)
                },

                //This creates and shows a question of our question array
                //i:=JSON.questions array index
                showQuestion: function(i){
                    if (i >= 0 && i<this.mJSON.questions.length){
                        this.mCurrent = i;

                        var tQ = this.mJSON.questions[i];
                        var tN = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(tQ)[0]; //The property name is going to become the radio group name

                        //We are going to create a title (h1) and multiple radios (input & label) for each question
                        var tF = document.createDocumentFragment();

                        //Creating the header
                        var tH = document.createElement('h1');
                        tH.innerHTML = tQ.label;
                        tF.appendChild(tH);

                        //Creating the questions
                        for(var i=0, j=tQ[tN].length; i<j; i++){
                            var tR = document.createElement('input');
                            tR.type = 'radio';
                            tR.value = tQ[tN][i];
                            tR.name = tN;
                            tR.onchange = function(){Quiz._onChange(this)};
                            tF.appendChild(tR);

                            var tL = document.createElement('label');
                            tL.for = tR.name;
                            tL.innerHTML = tR.value;
                            tF.appendChild(tL);
                        }

                        //Now we are going to assign it to the dom.
                        this.mContainer.appendChild(tF)
                    }
                    else{
                        this.mCurrent = null;
                        this._Error('showQuestion(' + i.toString() + '): No such question loaded')
                    }
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = "Quiz.Init(document.querySelector('#Container'))">
        <div id = 'Container'>
            <!-- Container for the quiz -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### And the JSON.js

```
{
    "questions": [
        {"sex": ["male", "female"], "label": "What are you?"},
        {"food": ["tacos", "spicynuts"], "label": "What do you eat?"},
        {"team": ["team a", "team b", "team rocket"], "label": "Where do you belong to?"}
    ],

    "answers": [
        {"requirement": ["male", "tacos", "team a"], "message": "one has chosen male, tacos and team a"},
        {"requirement": ["female", "tacos", "team a"], "message": "one has chosen female, tacos and team a"}
    ]
}
```

## Edit:

A small question occured to me while writing my suggestion. Given your explanation "there are seven questions and five results". Do some outcomes share results or have none?

### Changes

To solve the sharing result issue, I though of two ways which I think are the most simple to input and maintain.

#### We list the result twice

This solution might sound silly and too simple. Yet it is easy to maintain and manage. The obvious downfall is the lack of data integrity.

```
{"requirement": ["male", "spicynuts", "team a"], "message": "one has chosen male, spicynuts and team a"},
{"requirement": ["female", "spicynuts", "team a"], "message": "one has chosen male, spicynuts and team a"}
```

#### We nest lists on requirements

Another way is to nest requirements (array in array/object), so that one may simply list more requirements with same message. The downfall here is, that even if one never needs it, one had to structure it that way.

```
{
    "requirement": [
        ["male", "tacos", "team rocket"],
        ["male", "spicynuts", "team rocket"],
        ["female", "tacos", "team rocket"],
        ["female", "spicynuts", "team rocket"]
    ],
    "message": "team rocket rocks my socks!"
}
```

#### Conclusion

In the end I decided to let the user decide and support both methods and a combination of initial and solution number two. One can structure it like before, one can repeat answers with equal messages or one can nest requirements.

#### What do we need to change?

One function in the main code file

```
//Going to show the result according to the asked questions
showResult: function(){
    var tValues = []; //Storing our answers
    for(var i=0, j=this.mJSON.questions.length; i<j; i++)
        if (this.mJSON.questions[i].value) tValues.push(this.mJSON.questions[i].value)

    //Going to store the result text
    var tResult = 'No match for ' + tValues.join(',');

    //Looping through all requirements to get a match
    var tBreak = false; //We use this to double break both loops
    for(var i=0, j=this.mJSON.answers.length; i<j && !tBreak; i++){
        //The requirements which need to match the values
        var tR = this.mJSON.answers[i].requirement;

        //We put simple arrays in a nested array to keep the same logic/process
        var tRR = (typeof tR[0] === 'string') ? [tR] : tR;

        for(var k=0, l=tRR.length; k<l && !tBreak; k++){
            //For this we filter all the elements which do not match the requirements
            var tF = tValues.filter(function(e){return tRR[k].indexOf(e) === -1})

            //If that list is empty, all elements matched and we can stop
            if (!tF || tF.length === 0){
                tResult = this.mJSON.answers[i].message;
                tBreak = true;
            }
        }

        //If that list is empty, all elements matched and we can stop
        if (!tF || tF.length === 0){
            tResult = this.mJSON.answers[i].message;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Now we are going to dislpay the result
    var tH = document.createElement('h1');
    tH.innerHTML = tResult;
    this.mContainer.appendChild(tH)
},
```

And here is the sample JSON used for testing

```
{
    "questions": [
        {"sex": ["male", "female"], "label": "What are you?"},
        {"food": ["tacos", "spicynuts"], "label": "What do you eat?"},
        {"team": ["team a", "team b", "team rocket"], "label": "Where do you belong to?"}
    ],

    "answers": [
        {"requirement": ["male", "tacos", "team a"], "message": "one has chosen male, tacos and team a"},
        {"requirement": ["female", "tacos", "team a"], "message": "one has chosen female, tacos and team a"},

        {"requirement": ["male", "spicynuts", "team a"], "message": "one has chosen male, spicynuts and team a"},
        {"requirement": ["female", "spicynuts", "team a"], "message": "one has chosen male, spicynuts and team a"},

        {
            "requirement": [
                ["male", "tacos", "team rocket"],
                ["male", "spicynuts", "team rocket"],
                ["female", "tacos", "team rocket"],
                ["female", "spicynuts", "team rocket"]
            ],
            "message": "team rocket rocks my socks!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Some outcomes could share results. Any suggestions on that? I have accepted your answer as it's the logic I liked the most, but hopefully it's not problematic with 'shared results'. Any thoughts? There will be no outcomes that have zero results. This can branch off into a new question if you don't have any easy edit to your answer.

Comment: @YourConscious: Unfortunately, I am at work for a few more hours. Yet if you have some time and patience I will gladly think about an extended version.

Comment: @YourConscious: There you go.

Answer (score 3):

I think it could have been better but here is the start.

Put all logic in array.

http://jsfiddle.net/1exsro2b/1/

```
var logics = {
    idOfDiv: [{idOfInput: valueOfInput ,name:'asd',gender:'female'} , {name:'bbb'}],
    ifn2: [{num:1}],
    ifn3: [{gender:'male'}],
    ifn4: [{name:'zxc'}]
};

/*
basically give ids to divs that you want to show conditionally starting with ifn and in array put logic [{formEleId: value, ...},{...or logic..}]
*/

var rules = Object.keys(logics);
var divs = $('div[class^=ifn]').hide();
var form = $("#inputs");

updateForm();

form.on('input change', function () {
    updateForm();
    console.log($('#gender')[0]);
});

function updateForm() {
    divs.hide();
    rules.forEach(function (k) {
        var ele = divs.filter("." + k);
        logics[k].forEach(function(l) {
            applyRules(l,ele);
        });
    });
}

function applyRules(l, ele){
    var ids = Object.keys(l);
    var valid = true;
    ids.forEach(function(id){
        var input = form.find('#'+id);
        if (input.children('input:radio').length>0){
            input = input.children('input[type=radio]:checked');
        }
        if (input.val() != l[id]) valid = false;
    });
    if (valid) ele.show();
}
```

Comment: you can simulate and, or logic, haven't implemented not, only logic. or range of values.

Comment: I'd like to see all the code here, not just some of it, but this seems very powerful (more power than the OP asked for, actually, but that isn't a bad thing).  I'd be curious as to why it wasn't accepted by the OP.

Comment: @GuySchalnat there should be library that does this..i've always felt jquery isn't good tool to put lots of manual logic into code, just too messy

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
var val1=$('input[name="sex"]:checked', '#page1').val()
var val2=$('input[name="food"]:checked', '#page1').val()

 if (val1 == "male" && val2== "tacos") {
    $('#resultsONE').show();   
  } else if () {
    // do
  } else {
    // do
  }

});
```

This is just the sample logic, may need some tweak to make it work for you

Answer (score 1):

How about making use of the `data` attributes to make the process simpler?

```
<div class="page1" data-answer-div="results-one">
    <form class="sampler">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="checked" data-answer="a1" />Male
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" data-answer="a2" />Female
    </form>
</div>

<div id="results-one">
    <div class="a a1">
        <p>Congratulations, you are NOT the father</p>
    </div>
    <div class="a a2">
        <p>Congratulations, you are NOT the mother</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, when the input is changed, you could hide any div's with the class `.a` within the `answer-div`. So, in the above example, you'd  hide the `div.a`'s in `#results-one`, and then show the div with the corresponding `a[n]` class.

```
$('input').change(function () {
    var answerDiv = $(this).closest('div').data('answer-div');
    $('#' + answerDiv).find('div.a').hide();
    $('#' + answerDiv).find('div.' + $(this).data('answer')).show();
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/d4jn1hyb/), and [here's a fiddle with multiple forms.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/d4jn1hyb/1/)

Comment: I am not entirely certain, yet it seems like the questions should get evaluated as cominations (i.e. male && taco) and not seperately. At least that is how I comprehended the post.

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways to answer this, I'm going to add AngularJS into the mix, mostly because it sort of looks like the library that OP may be looking for (without really asking for it).

```js
angular.module('angularSolution', []).controller('angularController', function($scope) {

  // initialize values
  $scope.sex = "male";
  $scope.food = "tacos";
  $scope.hideResultsONE = false;

  // function called when a radio button is clicked
  $scope.radioChange = function() {

    // this could be one line of code, but I find it easier to read using all five lines
    if ($scope.sex == "male" && $scope.food == "tacos") {
      $scope.hideResultsONE = false;
    } else {
      $scope.hideResultsONE = true;
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html data-ng-app="angularSolution">

<body data-ng-controller="angularController">
  <div class="page1">
    <form class="sampler">
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" data-ng-model="sex" data-ng-change="radioChange()">Male
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" data-ng-model="sex" data-ng-change="radioChange()">Female
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="page2">
    <form class="sampler">
      <input type="radio" name="food" value="tacos" data-ng-model="food" data-ng-change="radioChange()">Tacos
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="food" value="spicynuts" data-ng-model="food" data-ng-change="radioChange()">Rotten Spicy Peanuts
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="resultsONE" data-ng-hide="hideResultsONE">
    <!-- one results div is display none by default sample but there would be much more content here  -->
    <p>Congratulations, you are NOT the father</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you wanted to, you could put the expression to determine whether to show or hide the div inside the data-ng-hide attribute, but I prefer it in code, actually.  It's less hidden that way.

Basically, this is the same answer as others have given, but AngularJS has two-way data bound the variables.  There is many other things AngularJS will do for you, but that is outside the scope of this question.

If you look back to your original code in the question, this is pretty close.  The data binding mean that the variables in $scope are already set up with the values, and showing or hiding merely mean setting another variable, not calling a function directly, but all that is really left in the function is the logic that you described.

Comment: I have chosen the best answer to my preference, but I think yours is second inline after the JSON accepted answer +1.

Comment: I like the accepted answer as well.  There was always going to be more than one valid answer here, and which one is best for you or any others seeking similar things depends more on the details of the particular problem at hand (how many questions and answers and how convoluted the logic is), than one being strictly better than the other.  I'm glad we could offer different choices, and I upvoted a few other answers myself.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using complicated if statements, I would suggest to add a data attribute on your divs which include the combination of selections you require to have that div show.

I have replaced the values with numeric references to keep the code simple, but it works either way.

Hope I got your requirements right.

http://jsfiddle.net/kxsb00ps/

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    <form class="sampler">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="1" />Male
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="2" />Female</form>
</div>
<div class="page">
    <form class="sampler">
        <input type="radio" name="food" value="1" />Tacos
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="food" value="2" />Rotten Spicy Peanuts</form>
</div>
<input id="submitBtn" type="button" value="submit"/>
<div class="results">
    <div data-selection="1,1" >
        <p>You are a male who likes Tacos</p>
    </div>
    <div data-selection="2,1">
        <p>You are a female who likes Tacos</p>
    </div>
    <div data-selection="1,2">
        <p>You are a male who likes Rotten Spicy Peanuts</p>
    </div>
    <div data-selection="2,2">
        <p>You are a female who likes Rotten Spicy Peanuts</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JavaScript (using jQuery for selectors):

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){
    // create an empty array
    var selectedData = [];
    // iterate each page
    $(".page").each(function(){
        // place the selections in an array
        selectedData.push($(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked").val());
    });

    // clear previous results
    $(".results > div").hide();

    // find the div using the data attribute
    $(".results").find("[data-selection='" + selectedData + "']").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to combine the selected values to a div name you want to display. For example if one has the values male and tacos selected the div with the name 'male-tacos' gets displayed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .result{display: none}
            .page{margin: 10px}
        </style>

        <script>
            //Binding the radio change even on all radio boxes contained in page classes
            function Init(){
                var tL = document.querySelectorAll('.page input[type="radio"]');
                for(var i=0, j= tL.length; i<j; i++) tL[i].onchange = function(){evalAnswers()}
            };

            function evalAnswers(){
                //Getting all checked radio buttons
                var tL = document.querySelectorAll('.page input[type="radio"]:checked');

                //Combining the values to get the result name
                var tS = [];
                for(var i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++) tS.push(tL[i].value);

                //Getting the result div
                var tR = document.querySelector('[name="' + tS.join('-') + '"]');

                //If we have no result for the combination showing the __unhandled named div
                if (!tR) tR = document.querySelector('[name="__unhandled"]');

                //Hiding all results again (might not be needed if no replay option)
                var tL = document.querySelectorAll('.result');
                for(var i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++) tL[i].style.display = 'none';

                //Showing the result
                if (tR) tR.style.display = 'block';
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'Init()'>
        <!-- page1 looks more like an id than a class -->
        <div class = 'page' id = 'page1'>
            <input type = 'radio' name = 'sex' value = 'male' checked>Male
            <br>
            <input type = 'radio' name = 'sex' value = 'female'>Female
        </div>

        <div class = 'page' id = 'page2'>
            <input type = 'radio' name = 'food' value = 'tacos' checked>Tacos
            <br>
            <input type = 'radio' name = 'food' value = 'spicynuts'>Spicynuts
        </div>

        <div class = 'page' id = 'page3'>
            <input type = 'radio' name = 'color' value = 'red' checked>Red
            <br>
            <input type = 'radio' name = 'color' value = 'blue'>Blue
        </div>

        <!-- the name is the combinations of answers, with this we can select the correct div -->
        <div class = 'result' name = 'male-tacos-red'>
            male-tacos-red
        </div>

        <div class = 'result' name = 'female-tacos-blue'>
            male-tacos-red
        </div>

        <div class = 'result' name = '__unhandled'>
            unhandled result
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/31mebxkk/

Like this one may merely change the HTML without worrying about the script itself.

Comment: While I would use a data- attribute instead of the name (and a library instead of pure javascript), I like the concept in this answer.  It makes it really easy to control which divs are shown when.  No, it doesn't seperate out logic and markup, but OP was going for something simple, and it is simple to control.